# File Too Large to import?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I just wrote this code to fetch the wireshark mac oui database, and I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "init.py", line 38, in <module>
    main()
  File "init.py", line 27, in main
    import maclist
  File "/home/synthetica/WiJam/maclist.py", line 23753
    'FC:F6:4
```

however, this is NOT the contents of the file at that line. Is this a limit of the python intepreter, something I'm overlooking, or something else?

init.py:

```
def main():
    #init
     #Load config.
    import localconfig
    print localconfig.name
     #update mac adress db, if at all possible:
    try:
        import maclist
    except:
        import urllib2
        print "Fetching MAC adress db."
        try:
            maclist = urllib2.urlopen(localconfig.url)
        else:
            fl = open("maclist.py","w")
            fl.write("#maclist.py generated by "+localconfig.name+"\n")
            print "Generating maclist.py"
            for line in maclist:
                if "#" in line: line=line[:line.index("#")]
                line = line.split()
                if line and "-" not in line[0]:
                    line=[repr(part) for part in line]
                    line = "=".join(line)
                    fl.write("=".join(line.split())+"\n")
    import maclist



 #start browser

#start web interface
 #handle web interface commands
 #display web interface

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

localconfig.py

```
version = "0.3"
name = "Synth's WiJam (version "+version+")"

#maclist related:
url = "https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob_plain;f=manuf;hb=HEAD"
```

Any leads?

@bren
maclist.py: Not the full thing, heavens no. It's 20k+ lines.

```
'FC:E1:92'='SichuanJ'
'FC:E1:D9'='StableIm'
'FC:E2:3F'='ClayPaky'
'FC:E5:57'='Nokia'
'FC:E8:92'='Hangzhou'
'FC:ED:B9'='Arrayent'
'FC:F1:CD'='Optex-Fa'
'FC:F5:28'='ZyxelCom'
'FC:F6:47'='Fiberhom'
'FC:F8:AE'='IntelCor'
'FC:F8:B7'='TronteqE'
'FC:FA:F7'='Shanghai'
'FC:FB:FB'='Cisco'
```

Comment: Is ```'FC:F6:4``` anywhere in the file?  If so, how far off is it?

Comment: Yes. However, the full line is correct: 'FC:F6:47'='Fiberhom'

Comment: That doesn't look like valid Python.  Can you paste the relevant few lines around that line from `maclist.py`?

Comment: So just to clarify, the partial contents are shown in the traceback, but it is at the right position (ie line 23753 is ```'FC:F6:47'='Fiberhom'```)

Comment: Yeah. Also, @BrenBarn, it's in the full question

Comment: What you pasted isn't valid Python code (unless it's inside a big string or something).  You can't assign a value to a string.  What is `maclist.py` supposed to be?

Comment: If you were to try to `import` a file like that it should throw `SyntaxError: can't assign to literal` since.. well, you can't.  Why are you trying to `import` it?  Is this just an attempt at serializing some data by hand?

Comment: @Synthetica, is there somewhere you can upload the full file (provided it doesn't have any sensitive information) for us to look at?  Clearly the problem is deeper than the line throwing the error

Comment: Is that the full contents of the traceback? There should be more, I would expect...

Comment: I'll Upload it to my dropbox, 1 min. It's also generated from running the code btw.

Comment: You never close the `fl` file handler, so your writes are never fully flushed to disk. That could be a problem...

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6633808/maclist.py

Comment: yeah, that's not valid Python

Comment: Invalid Python it is.

Comment: You need to rethink how you're doing this.  You can't just put anything of the form `'X:Y:Z' = 'blah'` into a file and expect to be able to import it as a Python module.  You should write some code to actually parse your file format, or use some standard file format like JSON.

Comment: I see now. But the source of the problem is the unclosed fl file handler indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite maclist.py to be proper python syntax, for example:

```
hosts={} 
hosts['FC:FA:F7']='Shanghai'
hosts['FC:FB:FB']='Cisco'
```

and so on.

Comment: Thanks. It's not the core problem of this question (the unclosed fl handler), but it was the next step indeed.